# Rebol MSAccess ODBC: works with DNS connection but not with DNSLess Connection

Tags: ms-access, dns, rebol

I have tested the new free Rebol ODBC with MS Access after reading the doc here

http://www.rebol.com/docs/database.html

It works with ODBC DNS connection but when I tested with this DNSLess connection (MSAccess2003 file with MSAccess2007 installed):

```
connect-name: open [
    scheme: 'odbc
    target: join "{DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; "
        "DBQ=c:\test\test.mdb"
]
```

It shows this error:

```
>>     connect-name: open [
[            scheme: 'odbc
[            target: join "{DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; "
[                "DBQ=c:\test\test.mdb"
[        ]
** Access Error: Invalid port spec: scheme odbc target join {DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};
  DBQ=c:\test\test.mdb
** Near: connect-name: open [
    scheme: 'odbc
    target: join "{DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; "
    "DBQ=c:\test\...
>>
>>
```

Do you know why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're using Rebol 2.7.7 core which does not come with ODBC.  You need to use View.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link

http://synapse-ehr.com/forums/showthread.php?18-Rebol-odbc

for the example